# How to graph a 3D surface over a general region using Geogebra?

Tags: graphing-functions, 3d, surfaces

Good day.
I want to teach double integral using 3D GeoGebra as a tool.

I am trying to illustrate the following problem in GeoGebra.

$$ \int_0^{1}\Biggl\{\int_0^{\sqrt{x}} xy \;dy \Biggl\}\;dx $$

How can I graph the top surface of the solid over the given region?

I use the following entry to graph the top surface over the given region:

$$ 0\leq x\leq 1\ ; 0\leq y \leq \sqrt{x}$$

The upper curve is $u(x)=x$, and the lower curve is $l(x)=x^2$.

**`top=Surface(j,u(j)-l(k),f(j,u(j)-l(k)),j,0,1,k,0,1)`**

Here is the link to my output for your reference.

[GeoGebra Double integral over a general region](https://www.geogebra.org/classic/zgtxpta6)

However, the code only produces a top surface below the curve $u(x)$.

Comment: Instead of a parametric representation, use the $z=f(x,y)$ representation: $z=x*y*(y<x^2)$

Comment: Thank you, @JeanMarie